# scrapy not exporting data to elastic search

Tags: search, scrapy, elasticsearch

I want to index my items in ElasticSearch, I found [this](https://github.com/noplay/scrapy-elasticsearch).

But if i'm trying to crawl a site I get the following error:

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks
>               current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyelasticsearch/scrapyelasticsearch.py", line 70, in process_item
>               self.index_item(item)
>             File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyelasticsearch/scrapyelasticsearch.py", line 52, in index_item
>               local_id = hashlib.sha1(item[uniq_key]).hexdigest()
>             File "/home/javed/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 50, in **getitem**
>               return self._values[key]
>           exceptions.KeyError: 'url'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you didn't paste your spider code, I can only assume things.
One assumption would be that you didn't set the required filed in your items. They need to have a field specified in `ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY`, and it has to be unique. The simplest thing might be to use the `url`:

```
# somewhere deep in your callback, 
# where you create and yield your item
...
myitem['url'] = response.url
return myitem
```

and make sure to set in the `settings.py`:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY = 'url'
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply commented this field in my settings.py file (this field is optional according to [official documentation](https://github.com/knockrentals/scrapy-elasticsearch))

```
#ELASTICSEARCH_UNIQ_KEY = 'url'  # Custom unique key
```